# Apache Jena ARQ string representation

Tags: sparql, jena, apache-jena

I have a Apache Jena ARQ SPARQL query of the form

```
SELECT DISTINCT  (count(*) AS ?rowCount) ......
```

The rowCount value is coming in as `1^^http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer`

This is causing problems in parsing the integer value , how do I ensure that only the number in this case 1 is returned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the number 1 - an xsd:integer with lexical form "1".  You have shown it in full form.  Syntaxes like Turle write it a 1 (no quotes) - it's just a short hand abbreviation for "1"^^xsd:integer.

If you want just the lexical part, get the literal then parse the lexical form (Literal.getLexicalForm).